# Rewrite url with subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got domain main project for this domain in web directory. Now I need to place similar project in subdirectory of domain's root.

```
domain.com
|-web
|   |-index.php
|   |-assets
|
|-subdirectory
|   |-web
|       |index.php
|       |-assets
```

My example url for first project domain.com/homepage is rewriting to domain.com/web/index.php?url=homepage using htaccess. Assets url is rewrites to assets directory.

*/.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
```

*/web/.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|png|jpe?g|ico|swf|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]

# rewrite assets version to orginal location
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} assets/([0-9]+)/
RewriteRule ^assets/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ assets/$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works well but how to extend this htaccess or add another .htaccess in subdirectory to rewriting subdirectory url?

Example **domain.com/subdirectory/homepage** sholud be rewrite to **domain.com/subdirectory/web/index.php?url=homepage**

**SOLUTION:**

*/.htaccess* and */subdirectory/.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

*/web/.htaccess* and */subdirectory/web/.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|png|jpe?g|ico|swf|js|css)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]

    # rewrite assets version to orginal location
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} assets/([0-9]+)/
    RewriteRule ^assets/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ assets/$2

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Finally:

***domain.com/start*** rewrites to ***domain.com/web/index?url=start***

***domain.com/subdirectory/start*** rewrites to ***domain.com/subdirectory/web/index?url=start***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the `/subdirectory` rewrite on root directory, and apply `htaccess` rules under the folder `subdirectory` same as root directory.

**/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Alost works but it works only for url **domain.com/subdirectory**. Urls like **domain.com/subdirectory/homepage** are rewriting to  **domain.com/web/index.php?url=homepage**. What is wrong?

Comment: This `RewriteCond` excludes the uri with prefix `/subdirectory`, possible cause could be the problem of `/subdirectory/.htaccess`, edit your questions to include `/subdirectory/.htaccess`